# Count array created by msql selection

Tags: php, mysql, count

I need to select some images inside a table by its ID (duplicate entrys allowed).

My maincode:

```
...
$selectedImages = $this->selectImages($selectedNews['ID'][$i]);
//Check values
echo 'Count of Array: '.sizeof($selectedImages)."\n";
if (sizeof($selectedImages) == 0) {
    $this->html[] = '-';
} else {
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($selectedImages); $j++) {
        $this->html[] = '<a class="fancybox single_image" href="/'.$selectedImages['Path'][$j].$selectedImages['Name'][$j].'"><img src="thumbnail/thumb.php?src=../../'.$selectedImages['Path'][$j].$selectedImages['Name'][$j].'&amp;h=50&amp;w=50" alt="'.$selectedImages['Name'][$j].'" /></a>';
    }
}
...
```

and this is my Method:

```
private function selectImages($id) {
        $selectedImages = array();

        $sql = "SELECT
                    Name,
                    Path
                FROM 
                    News_images
                WHERE
                    Pos = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $id)."'
                ";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        if (!$result = $this->db->query($sql)) {
            echo 'Datenbankfehler\n';
            echo $this->db->error;
        }

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $selectedImages['Path'][$i] = $row['Path'];
            $selectedImages['Name'][$i] = $row['Name'];
            $i++;
        }

        echo 'Selected: '.$i.' images ,';

        return $selectedImages;
}
```

I get following output:
Selected 1 images, Count of Array: 2
Selected 0 images, Count of Array: 0
Selected 4 images, Count of Array: 2

The actual amount of selected images is the correct one. But the count of the Array does not match the count of the actual selection.

Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof($selectedImages);` will give you `2` as it has actually two elements: 'Path' and 'Name'. Use:

```
sizeof($selectedImages['Path']) ...
```

or

```
sizeof($selectedImages['Name']) ...
```

to respect your current array structure.

---

Btw: Wouldn't an array structure like the following not being better? ;)

```
$selectedImages = array (
    array('Path' => '...', 'Name' => '...'),
    array('Path' => '...', 'Name' => '...'),
    ....
);
```

To achieve this you'll just have to simplify your mysql fetch code:

```
$selectedImages = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $selectedImages[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Check my update about your array structure. You should change it

Comment: :) Note that after that change you'll have to use `sizeof($selectedImages);` again